# После 39 строки не выполняются команды, почему? Как это исправить?

Tags: pascal

Задача;

> В аэробусе, вмещающем 160 пассажиров, три четверти мест находятся в салоне экономического класса и одна четверть мест — в салоне бизнес-класса.
> Стоимость билета в салоне бизнес-класса составляет х рублей, что в два раза выше стоимости билета в салоне экономического класса.

Цель:

> Необходимо вычислить сумму денег, полученную авиакомпанией от продажи билетов на один рейс, если известно, что остались нераспроданными a билетов бизнес-класса и b билетов экономического класса.
> Зафиксируйте свои действия на каждом из этапов решения задачи.

```
program air_1;
  var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, x, y, k, l, v: real;
  //a - Не распроданные билеты бизнес-класса.
  //b - Не распроданные билеты эконом-класса.
  //c - Количество мест в бизнес-классе.
  //d - Количество мест в эконом-классе.
  //e - Стоимость билета в бизнес-классе.
  //f - Стоимость билета в эконом-классе.
  //g - Общее количество мест в самолёте.
  //x - Количество проданных мест в бизнес-классе.
  //y - Количество проданных мест в эконом-классе.
  //k - Заработанные деньги за бизнес-класс.
  //l - Заработанные деньги за эконом-класс.
  //v - Общий зарабаток авиакомпании за этот рейс.
begin
  write('Введите количество мест в самолёте');
  readln(g);
  c:=g/4*3;
  d:=g/4*1;
  writeln('c = ', c);
  writeln('d = ', d);
  writeln('Введите стоимость билета в бизнес-классе');
  readln(e);
  f:=e/2;
  writeln('e = ', e);
  writeln('f = ', f);
  writeln('Сколько мест не продано в бизнес-классе');
  readln(x);
  x:=c-a;
  writeln('Сколько мест не продано в эконом-классе');
  readln(y);
  y:=d-b;
  k:=x*e;
  readln(k);
  l:=y*f;
  readln(l);
  writeln('Компания заработала на бизнес-классе ', k, ' Рублей.');
  writeln('Компания заработала на эконом-классе ', l, ' Рублей.');
  v:=k+l;
  readln(v);
  writeln('Авиакомпания получила за этот рейс ', v, ' Рублей.');
end.
```

Comment: предлагаете нам строки считать тут сидеть? Как вы определяете что она не выполняете, и что там по ошибкам

Comment: После ввода "Сколько мест не продано в эконом-классе" программа не выполняет след. команды. Ошибку ни какую не выдаёт.

Comment: Очень странная строка `readln(k);` сразу после вычисления этого самого `k`. Полагаю, что тут опечатка, должен был быть `writeln`, и "не выполняется" означает ожидание ввода пользователя.

Comment: уберите строки `readln(k)`, `readln(l)`

Answer (score 1):

у вас присутствует две лишние стоки:

```
readln(k)
```

и

```
readln(l)
```

код должен выглядеть так:

```
program air_1;
  var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, x, y, k, l, v: real;
begin
  write('Введите количество мест в самолёте');
  readln(g);
  c:=g/4*3;
  d:=g/4*1;
  writeln('c = ', c);
  writeln('d = ', d);
  writeln('Введите стоимость билета в бизнес-классе');
  readln(e);
  f:=e/2;
  writeln('e = ', e);
  writeln('f = ', f);
  writeln('Сколько мест не продано в бизнес-классе');
  readln(x);
  x:=c-a;
  writeln('Сколько мест не продано в эконом-классе');
  readln(y);
  y:=d-b;
  k:=x*e;
  l:=y*f;
  writeln('Компания заработала на бизнес-классе ', k, ' Рублей.');
  writeln('Компания заработала на эконом-классе ', l, ' Рублей.');
  v:=k+l;
  readln(v);
  writeln('Авиакомпания получила за этот рейс ', v, ' Рублей.');
end.
```